# What front derailleur is this? Want to replace/upgrade

Tags: derailleur, replacement

Hi I've bought a foldable bike and am thinking of changing the derailleurs to Shimano, but I could not figure out what type it is.

The link the to the bike is:
https://www.forever-bicycle.com/html/show-22-29-1.html

It says **MICROSHIFT FD-42F** could not find it on Microshift's website .. and googling seemed to only give results to the product pages of the bike itself. Any chance that this might be a customized item?

***To further this question:***

If this FD is a customized item .. what are the other alternatives I have? Or is advisable to just switch to internal rear hub?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As the owner of a folder, an IGH would be wonderful.  The 20" wheel means the derailleur hangs very low, and the whole drivetrain gets a lot dirtier than a larger bike.  If you can afford an Alfine or Nexus, then go for it.  The 11 speed would be great, 8 speed okay, but I'd avoid the 3 speeds for lack of range.

Comment: Microshift started out almost exclusively producing for the OEM rather than retail markets, so its not surprising a part is not listed on their website.

Comment: Based on part number its probably a variation on http://mail.microshift.com.tw/FD-R42h_city_fd.html but with braze-on rather than band-on fitting.  If its working okay, you don't need to change it.

Comment: Why do you want to change the FD?

Answer (score 6):

Its called a "braze-on" front derailleur.

The matching opposite format is a "band-on" or "band clamp" and goes around the seat tube.

[image: https://cdnmos-bikeradar.global.ssl.fastly.net/images/news/2015/05/28/1432779227484-1uv5qnvs7opm2-630-354.jpg]

Be careful when torquing the single bolt in your braze-on fitting.  Too loose and it will move while shifting.  Too tight and it will strip the thread and move while shifting.

---

Separately - the cable is disappearing downward, so it can be described as "Bottom Pull" or "Bottom Normal"

I can only see one other chainring, so this seems to be on a bike with a double chainring.

**Answer** Its a **braze-on bottom-pull front double mech.**

If your question is about groupset - look closely for engraved or embossed model numbers.  I can't recognise it.

The front derailleur is not a critical part and given its more about brute force than finesse you can get away with a very low groupset front mech perfectly well.   Sora and Tiagra will work fine with a 105 or ultegra rest-of-system, with some minor variance based on chainring separation distance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I know where to start searching!! :)